# Java Hibernate org.hibernate.annotations.Index

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing

i am implementing Indexing in my DB i was wondering if this annotations only works on D.D.L. We got a legacy System this sentence dont works if the schema is not generated?.

is ignored?

my code

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "person",indexes={@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "part_of_name",columnNames={"c01"})})
```

i was checking the docs and the doc for `INDEX` is almost empty. take a look

[Doc for Index](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is right, this is basically a DDL annotation. The `@Index` will have an effect (i.e. a new index will be created) only be by setting hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto hibernate property to update